# How to keep outer class variables used in inner class without listing them in proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

```
package com.hello

public class Outer extends Activity{
  int a;
  int b;
  array c;
  Boolean bol;

  public void onCreate() {
    a=1;
    b=2;
    c=new int[10];
    bol=true;
  }

  class Inner implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
      if (bol)
        for (int e=0;e<10;e++) c[e]=a+b;
    }   
  }
}
```

How can I tell Progruad to keep the name of the inner class and the variables used in the inner class even though they are defined in the onCreate method?

I don't want to list each variable one by one.

Answer (score 0):

to keep inner classes:

```
# specific class (in brackets for example we keep all)* 
-keep class OuterFQNClassName$InnerClassName { *; }   
# all inner classes of outer class 
 -keep class OuterFQNClassName$** { *; }
# all inner classes 
 -keepattributes InnerClasses
```

to keep fields with desired public/protected/private/default access level modifiers):

```
# for specific class 
-keepclassmembers class FQNClassName {
    protected <fields>;    
}

# for all classes 
-keepclassmembers class * {
    protected <fields>; 
}

# other approach for default acl
# be careful as method could have also native modifiers :) 
-keepclassmembers class * {
  !public !protected !private *;
}
```

*naming convention with a '$' separator between the names of inner classes and outer classes

please study a proguard docs:

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/attributes